# how to change a column with both negative and positive value into two columns with negative value plus zero and positive value plus zero

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

My data is the following:

```
t  B
1  2
2 -3
3 -7
```

How could i have the output like below? It means that when the data from column B is negative, the column N will equal this columnB's data,or it will equal to zero. On the contrary, when the data from column B is positive, the column P will equal this data, or it will equal to zero.

```
t   B  N  P
1   2  0  2
2  -3 -3  0
3  -7 -7  0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `pmin`/`pmax` here

```
transform(df, N = pmin(B, 0), P = pmax(B, 0))

#   B  N P
#1  2  0 2
#2 -3 -3 0
#3 -7 -7 0
```

---

Another approach could be

```
transform(df, N = B * (B < 0), P = B * (B > 0))
```

**data**

```
df<- structure(list(B = c(2L, -3L, -7L)), class = "data.frame", 
     row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `ifelse` here for a base R option:

```
df <- data.frame(t=c(1:3), B=c(2, -3, -7))
df$N <- ifelse(df$B < 0, df$B, 0)
df$P <- ifelse(df$B >= 0, df$B, 0)
df

  t  B  N P
1 1  2  0 2
2 2 -3 -3 0
3 3 -7 -7 0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also do

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   rowwise %>% 
   mutate(N = min(B, 0), P = max(B, 0))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#      B     N     P
#  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     2     0     2
#2    -3    -3     0
#3    -7    -7     0
```

#### data

```
df<- structure(list(B = c(2L, -3L, -7L)), class = "data.frame", 
     row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))
```